# dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib

Tags: electron, electron-builder

Using electron-builder to build Windows app, When signing up, I got this error :

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/puss/Library/Caches/electron-builder/winCodeSign/winCodeSign-1.7.0/darwin/osslsigncode
  Reason: image not found
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59006602/dyld-library-not-loaded-usr-local-opt-openssl-lib-libssl-1-0-0-dylib/59184347#59184347

Comment: The exact same error happens when you try to run `watchman watch-del-all` as suggested by the iOS simulator running React Native.

Answer (score 49):

If you are in MacOS 10.15 (Catalina), try this (reinstall openssl):

```
brew update && brew upgrade
brew uninstall openssl
brew install https://github.com/tebelorg/Tump/releases/download/v1.0.0/openssl.rb
```

Comment: Nice one, seems like the the new brew formula is broken, can't link it, etc. This works.

Comment: Still on MacOS 10.11.6 (El Capitan) myself, this was a big help for me, too: finally got mysql2 to build on a ruby 1.9.3 env..

Comment: If having `openssl` already installed. Please uninstall it using `brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies openssl`. And then do `brew install https://github.com/tebelorg/Tump/releases/download/v1.0.0/openssl.rb`

Comment: when I did ```brew update && brew upgrade``` The issue resolved.

Comment: Worked like a charm on Mojave as well

Comment: Worked on Catalina as well.

Comment: If it is already installed, you can run `brew reinstall openssl@1.1`

Comment: little late to Party, But I can confirm this works perfectly on Mojave as I had to downgrade to Mojave from Catalina because of hibernate not working on Catalina anymore.

Comment: High Sierra and `brew update && brew upgrade` was everything I need to have it working again. TY

Comment: In Xcode 11.4 on macOS 10.5.4 (Catalina), this worked for building but when running my app, Xcode would complain that libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib "has no cdhash, completely unsigned". My updated project had Hardened Runtime enabled so I had to also enable "Disable Library Validation" in "Runtime Exceptions" in the "Signing & Capabilities" tab for my target.

Comment: ```brew update && brew upgrade``` solved the issue on Catalina as well. Thank you!

Comment: I received an error when trying to do `brew install https://github.com/tebelorg/Tump/releases/download/v1.0.0/openssl.rb`: `brew extract or brew create and brew tap-new to create a formula file in a tap on GitHub instead.: Invalid usage: Non-checksummed download of openssl formula file from an arbitrary URL is unsupported!  (UsageError)`. Downloading the file and doing `brew install -s openssl.rb` did the trick.

Comment: A simple brew update && brew upgrade worked for me.

Answer (score 38):

I try to uninstall openssl and reinstall openssl, It worked.

```
brew remove openssl
brew install openssl
```

Comment: I needed this after a Mac OSx Migrate

Comment: Works for me after migrating my MacBook.

Comment: If I try to remove openssl I get `Refusing to uninstall /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1g
because it is required by apr-util, elixir, erlang, freetds, httpd, libevent, libpq, libxml2, macvim, mysql, nghttp2, php71-mcrypt, postgresql, python, python@2, python@3.8, ruby, ruby-build, thefuck and wget, which are currently installed.`. If I uninstall, Might these libs stop working properly?

Comment: @AndreRavazzi I tried to uninstall anyway and reinstall, and it works fine

Comment: @AndreRavazzi yes, they might, but you're going to be re-installing openssl

Answer (score 31):

Just switch to `1.0.2t` version, using this command:

```
brew switch openssl 1.0.2t
```

Comment: In some cases the version is `1.0.2s`.

Comment: In my case it was 1.0.2s, switching to the older version solved the problem immediately

Comment: Why? Where did you get that version number?

Comment: `brew switch` was deprecated a year ago and doesn't appear to  work any more.

@Don'tPanic: `ls -al /usr/local/Cellar/openssl*`

Answer (score 15):

For me, re-installing **openssh** (not *openssl*) was the only solution.

```
brew remove openssh
brew install openssh
```

Comment: This blog also mentions this: https://blog.junjizhi.com/all/2019/12/17/git-fetch-libssl-error.html

Answer (score 3):

Thanks [unifreak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3776039/unifreak), I fixed this problem on macOS v10.11.6 at Tue Apr 28 2020 again.

> REF: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59224109/686105

1. Update homebrew index and upgrade. (option)

   ```
   [ chusiang@osx_el_capitan ~ ]
   $ brew update && brew upgrade
   ```
2. Try to remove the `openssl@1.1`.

   ```
   [ chusiang@osx_el_capitan ~ ]
   $ brew uninstall openssl@1.1
   Error: Refusing to uninstall /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1g
   because it is required by ansible-lint, atk, cairo, gdk-pixbuf, glib, gnupg, gnutls, gobject-introspection, gsettings-desktop-schemas, gtk+3, gtk-doc, harfbuzz, ipmitool, ipython, irssi, itstool, krb5, libevent, libfido2, libpq, libssh, libssh2, libxml2, macvim, meson, nmap, openssh, pango, pgcli, postgresql, python, python@2, python@3.8, ruby, rust, s3cmd, sdcv, sphinx-doc, sshuttle, tcpdump, tmate, tmux, travis, unbound, vim, w3m, wget and zenity, which are currently installed.
   You can override this and force removal with:
     brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies openssl@1.1
   ```
3. Remove the `openssl@1.1` with `--ignore-dependencies` args.

   ```
   [ chusiang@osx_el_capitan ~ ]
   $ brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies openssl@1.1
   Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1g... (8,052 files, 18.4MB)
   ```
4. Install the specific version of openssl v1.0.0.

   ```
   [ chusiang@osx_el_capitan ~ ]
   $ brew install https://github.com/tebelorg/Tump/releases/download/v1.0.0/openssl.rb
   ```
5. Lock the openssl version with v1.0.0.

   ```
   [ chusiang@osx_el_capitan ~ ]
   $ brew pin https://github.com/tebelorg/Tump/releases/download/v1.0.0/openssl.rb
   ```
6. Add this openssl into `$PATH`.

   ```
   [ chusiang@osx_el_capitan ~ ]
   $ echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
   ```
7. Apply this change of `$PATH`.

   ```
   [ chusiang@osx_el_capitan ~ ]
   $ source ~/.bash_profile
   ```
8. DONE.

   ```
   [ chusiang@osx_el_capitan ~ ]
   $ openssl version
   OpenSSL 1.0.2t  10 Sep 2019
   ```

Finally, the ssh / git / ansible were back !

Answer (score 3):

Here's what worked for me

```
brew update && brew upgrade
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies openssl 
brew install openssl
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. In my case, for a legacy Rails 2.4 app. It seems brew had updated /usr/local/opt/openssl to symlink to openssl@1.1/1.1.1d.

After trying several other things, I fixed it by manually updating the symlink /usr/local/opt/openssl to point to the 1.0.2s version that was already on my system:

```
MacBook-Pro/usr/local/opt(:|✔) % pwd
/usr/local/opt
MacBook-Pro/usr/local/opt(:|✔) % ll openssl*
lrwxr-xr-x  1 dhempy  admin  24 Feb 19 11:36 openssl -> ../Cellar/openssl/1.0.2s
lrwxr-xr-x  1 dhempy  admin  28 Feb 19 08:55 openssl@1.1 -> ../Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1d
```

Hopefully this is one-and-done for me, and I won't have to reapply that symlink after every update.

Comment: Three years later, this has proven to be a one-and-done for me, and I don't have to reapply that symlink after every update.

Answer (score 2):

`brew doctor` gave me the following warning:

```
Warning: Some installed formulae are missing dependencies.
You should `brew install` the missing dependencies:
  brew install openssl@1.1
```

this command fixed my issue

```
brew install openssl@1.1
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried each and every one of these answers and still was getting the error from question.

Solution was to:

1. `brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies openssl@<any&all brew ssl versions>`
2. remove the files manually from `/usr/local/etc` (the locations of these are listed after step 1)
3. *remedy the $PATH error*: aka tell ssh command where it should be looking, by adding `export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin` to `~/.zshrc` or `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc` depending on what shell you use.

hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling watchman with brew solved the issue for me :

`brew remove watchman`

`brew install watchman`

I hope it helps,

Answer (score 0):

This is the process I had to use to fix this issue. I am not sure how to use brew extract correctly.

We need openssl in order to use wget.

```
brew install openssl
```

Now, download version 1.0.2t and install it.

```
wget https://github.com/tebelorg/Tump/releases/download/v1.0.0/openssl.rb
brew install openssl.rb
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a conda env, simply use

```
conda install -c bioconda samtools openssl=1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to run these commands because my problematic package appeared to be `ldns`:

```sh
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies ldns
brew install ldns
```