# Mongodump/OpenSSL - "image not found" error

Tags: mongodb, openssl, homebrew, macos-catalina, mongodump

I recently updated macOS to Catalina and `mongodump` is no longer working.  I've updated

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/mongodb@3.6/bin/mongodump
  Reason: image not found
```

I see a few questions out there such as this one:  [dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44125147/dyld-library-not-loaded-usr-local-opt-openssl-lib-libcrypto-1-0-0-dylib).  This is the accepted response:

```
brew update && brew upgrade
brew uninstall openssl
brew install https://github.com/tebelorg/Tump/releases/download/v1.0.0/openssl.rb
```

However, I get this error when trying to install version 1.0.0:

```
Error: Calling Non-checksummed download of openssl formula file from an arbitrary URL is disabled! Use 'brew extract' or 'brew create' and 'brew tap-new' to create a formula file in a tap on GitHub instead.
```

Is there any way around this?  I'm not really sure where to go from that message.

Answer (score 0):

> You can check which version of Homebrew is installed by running `brew --version`
>
> You can use my previous response to implement how Homebrew now suggests it. Or if you want to use previous version of Homebrew to use these commands then follow this:
>
> 1. Go to Homebrew folder `cd /usr/local/Homebrew/`
> 2. Checkout to the previous version by running `git checkout 2.3.0`
> 3. To install OpenSSL `HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1 brew install https://github.com/tebelorg/Tump/releases/download/v1.0.0/openssl.rb`

Source: https://github.com/kelaberetiv/TagUI/issues/635#issuecomment-699482920